# App with media Player forces down

Tags: java, android

```
case R.id.btn7:
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(a.this, R.raw.aaaa);
    mp.start();
    break;
case R.id.btn8:
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(a.this, R.raw.bbbb);
    mp.start();
    break;
```

How could I use setDataSource in order to stop my app for force close? Please help!
If I use it like this, eclipse highlights red the setDataSource;

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
            mp.setDataSource(zoo.this,R.raw.gata);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            break;
```

Comment: i m creating a new mp for every button(16 btns total).How could i run my app with only one mp ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App forces down suddently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708221/app-forces-down-suddently)

Comment: mr kcoppock,do you have any answer on this problem please?it s not the same topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've actually been working on something similar for a hobby project I've been working on. After reading through the MediaPlayer documentation for a while, here is the method I've come up with (note that this is with the intention of having only a single sound playing at one time):

First, I created an overridden Application class to hold my global variables -- in this instance, my single MediaPlayer object:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {
    private static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mp;
    }
}
```

This creates one instance of a MediaPlayer once the application begins. It's also static, so it's available without having to instantiate the class.

Now, in my main class (particularly in my onClick method), I retrieve this instance, reset it, set my data source, prepare it for play, and then start it:

```
MediaPlayer mp = GlobalVars.getMediaPlayer();

//note that in my case, item is an object of mine that 
//contains an AssetFileDescriptor, which you can get by
//calling getAssets().openFd("filename.mp3");
AssetFileDescriptor afd = item.getDescriptor();

mp.reset();
//leaving out the try/catch block for conciseness
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: could you please be more specific on your comment//note that in my...("filename.mp3");

Comment: case R.id.btn:
                  MediaPlayer mp = GlobalVars.getMediaPlayer();

                                    
                  AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(R.raw.gata);mp.reset();
                                   mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());mp.prepare();mp.start(); break;

Comment: AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.gata);

Comment: is that a better way for my raw file?

Comment: Yeah, if you're using the Raw folder, I imagine that should work. In mine, I have my audio stored in folders under assets. Note that you probably can't call getResources() from within your click handler. You can declare it as a class variable and then initialize it in onCreate (e.g. `private Resource res;` as class variable, `res = getResources();` in onCreate). Then within your click handler, you can just call `res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.gata);`

Comment: if i add private resource res; as a class variable,eclipse prompts me to create a class with the name res...

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
            
    switch(v.getId()) {
                 case R.id.btn:
                  MediaPlayer mp = GlobalVars.getMediaPlayer();
                  AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                    R.raw.gata);
                   
                     mp.reset();
                    mp.setDataSource(fileDesc.getFileDescriptor(), fileDesc
                    .getStartOffset(), fileDesc.getLength());
                    fileDesc.close();
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();break;

Comment: this is what i m creating but eclipse highlight it...what could i change in order to fix it?

Comment: Should be `private Resources res;`. The capitalization is important.

Comment: i have tried to create a constructor for every file and then call it in the onClick..this works but sometimes the app freezes...please help11

Comment: You really have to stop posting code in comments, it's unreadable. Update your original question, just paste the code in, select it, and hit Ctrl+K to indent it. Then post your LogCat error log showing where the problem is, or if it's a compilation error, post what's not compiling.

Comment: Okay, I see it. Alright, really, my recommendation is that you really read through the whole documentation on MediaPlayer and get an understanding of it. You're still continually creating new MediaPlayer objects without releasing the previous resources, that's why you're getting the "Unable to create MediaPlayer" error, most likely. If you look at my answer, I'm never calling `new MediaPlayer` other than initially in the GlobalVars class. All other references to it call `reset()`, followed by `setDataSource()`, `prepare()`, and then `start()`.

Comment: i m sorry but i 'm a little confused...are you talking for edit 2?i believe that the best way is my first edit but i dont know how to get the setDataSource work!i really have read the MediaPlayer from the developers.android but i m really stacked on that..please, i'll be glad for your help!

Comment: Either one of your edits. I really don't know how else to explain it, you're creating multiple MediaPlayers with `new MediaPlayer()` and never releasing the resources. Rather, you should be reusing your once created MediaPlayer object (i.e. reset, setDataSource, prepare, start).

Comment: i have made a new try.in edit 2, i add mp.reset().you can see it in edit 3.is that ok?however is working...but i would like to know if thats a good way to solve my problem

Comment: Also, the reason your setDataSource method fails is that you're passing invalid arguments. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html If you look at the documentation, you'll see that there are *no* setDataSource methods which take a Context and an int (which is what R.raw.gata is). If you check your Errors window, or hover over the problem line, it will tell you this.

Comment: so how can i fix my setDataSource?setDataSource(R.raw.gata)?

Comment: You look at the methods that are available, and which parameters they take, and you pass the correct parameters. That's really just basic general programming. Not trying to be rude, but really that's just something basic you should be able to do. There's one that takes a Uri, and another that takes a FileDescriptor, which you've already gotten working above.

Comment: while running,edit 3 appers this as a warning in the logcat:01-18 17:03:54.936: WARN/System.err(940): java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: i know it but i have already done it,as you also said above..anyway,do you believe that edit 3 would be ok?i dont like the way that is written but its working for me..but as i was checking it in the logcat i saw the illegalstateexception

Comment: Why do you not like the way it is written? I do suggest using the method you used in your third edit; it is the way I originally suggested. Your exception is likely elsewhere in your code that you're calling prepare() or setDataSource() when the media player is in an invalid state.

Comment: could you please explain me ur second sentence because i cant understand it?

Comment: i dont like that in the onClick method i call the playLocalAudio_UsingDescriptor();.my code is about 400 lines with this way

Comment: Again, the docs... If you look at the MediaPlayer documentation, you'll see a flowchart at the top, detailing the states that the MediaPlayer can be in -- it's pretty complex. Below that, you'll see a listing of each of the methods, and what states you're allowed to use them in. For example, `prepare()` may only be called in the Initialized or Stopped state. Calling `prepare()` while in any other state results in an IllegalStateException.

Comment: Do you notice that all of your playLocalAudio... methods are identical...save for one parameter(your resource ID, R.raw.XXXX? Try making a generic method, that simply takes in that parameter, then you can simply iterate through and call the same method, just passing in a different ID each time.

Comment: Is edit4 what u are talking about?its ok now about the IllegalStateException?i think the problem is fixed mate

Comment: i erased the mp.start(); in the case,before break;,and i think that now it's ok,right??:)

Comment: The method looks good, but yeah, the whole `if(mp != null...)` statement, as well as the second `start()` method shouldn't be necessary, since the `reset()` call will stop the player anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sound manager if you finite no. of sounds to play.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Comment: the method i have created return a nullPointer exception..could you please be more specific on that?

Comment: do you mean something like this:

Comment: String url = "R.raw.aaaa";

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {

mp.setDataSource(url);

mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mp.prepare();

mp.start();

Comment: or if i move the mp3 files in the asset folder:

Comment: case R.id.btn:
                  String path = "/assets/aaaa.mp3";
                  
                  try {

                   mp.setDataSource(path);

                   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                   mp.prepare();

                   mp.start();

                   } catch (Exception e) {

                   Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = " + e);

                   }
                             break;